# Refreshing the component data based on the route in Angular

Tags: angular, angular8, router

I'm having a secondary navigation and the data in it needs to be changed based on the route. Please find the below image.

[image]

All the data which needs to be displayed on the component is stored as below.

```
export const Items: SecondaryNavItems[] = [
    {
        icon: 'far fa-copy', title: 'Newly Added Processes'
    },
    {
        icon: 'far fa-copy', title: 'Terminated Processes'
    },
    {
        icon: 'far fa-copy', title: 'Test Processes'
    },
    {
        icon: 'far fa-copy', title: 'Test Processes'
    }
];
```

This is the component.ts file.

```
export class SecondaryNavigationComponent implements OnInit {

  public navItems: any[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.navItems = Items.filter(navItem => navItem);
  }

}
```

Could someone tell me the optimal way to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure exactly what your issue is. Why not just load a component based on a route? Use ngOnInit within each component to load the data when the route is triggered.

Comment: @Muirik I don't think having multiple components for the same task is a good approach. Instead, I want to inject the data into the same component based on the route.

Comment: Are you passing anything in routes like this  `localhost:4200/get?terminatedProcess` ?

Comment: If you want to do it in same `component` then you can use `show/hide` with `if` conditions in `HTML` part of your component . Manage logic in your `typescript` file

Comment: @Wasim Still I think there's a proper way to inject the data to the component based on logic and it should be the proper way to implement this.

Comment: I guess You have to make component and then define routing

Comment: And then just append `component selector` in `HTML`  wherever you want to use it

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work when it's within the same component, you could use a subscription, in order to fire whenever the route changes, like so:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    this.animal = params.get("animal")
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to pass static data to `Route` is using the `data` property in `Routes` configuration

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'process', component: SomeComponent , data:{navItems: Items}},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found'}  
]
```

And it can be accessed inside your component using `ActivatedRoute`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.css']
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  navItems;
  constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.navItems= this.router.snapshot.data['navItems'];
    this.router.data.subscribe((data)=>{
      this.navItems= data['navItems'];
    })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a better way to implement this.

My Config file:

```
import { SecondaryList } from '../../models/secondary-nav';

export const Items: SecondaryList[] = [
    {
        type: 'bot',
        list: [
            {
                icon: 'far fa-copy', title: 'Test Processes 1'
            },
            {
                icon: 'far fa-copy', title: 'Test Processes 2'
            }
            ,{
                icon: 'far fa-copy', title: 'Test Processes 3'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        type: 'process',
        list: [
            {
                icon: 'far fa-copy', title: 'Test Processes 4'
            },
            {
                icon: 'far fa-copy', title: 'Test Processes 5'
            }
            ,{
                icon: 'far fa-copy', title: 'Test Processes 6'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.navItems = Items.filter(navItem => {
      return navItem.type === 'bot'
    });
  }
```

component.html

```
<div class = "row">
    <ng-container *ngFor ="let navItem of navItems">
        <div class = "col-md-3 axi-tile axi-tile--primary" *ngFor="let list of navItem.list">
                <div class = "axi-tile__icon">
                    <i [class]="list.icon"></i>
                </div>
                <div class = "axi-tile__text">{{list.title}}</div>
            
            </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```